# Speed up function evaluation for integration in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to port code from Matlab to SciPy. Here is the simplified version of the code I have written so far: https://gist.github.com/atmo/01b6e007be9ef90e402c . However, Python version is considerably slower then Matlab. I've included profiling results in the gist and they show that almost 90% of time python spends evaluating function `f`. Is there any way to speed up its evaluation, except from rewriting it in C or Cython?

Comment: you cannot get really fast in a dynamically typed language. If you want to get close to matlab you have to start statically typing your objects. I think `cython` is the right way to go. Why don't you want to use cython in the first place?

Comment: What kind of speed gain do you hope to obtain? I've had a look at your code and you can immediately gain a factor of 2 by taking into account the symmetry of your matrix. A few more optimizations on my side have reduced the run-time from 35.8s to 8.2s, but you might have hoped for better speed gains. In any case, brute copy-pasting from Matlab will result in suboptimal code (by the way, the comparison isn't entirely fair either: matlab has a JIT, CPython does not). Anyway, rewriting it in C still won't get rid of the numerous evaluations of `f`, which is done by `quad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can get rid of about half the calls to `quad` (and consequently the complicated function `f`) if you take into account that *the matrix is symmetric*.

Further speed gains, still in pure python, are to be had by rewriting that complicated function. I did most of that in sympy.

Finally I tried to vectorize the call to `quad` using `np.vectorize`.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.special import jn as besselj
from scipy import exp, zeros, linspace
from scipy.linalg import norm
import numpy as np

def complicated_func(lmbd, a, n, k):
    u,v,w = 5, 3, 2
    x = a*lmbd
    fac = exp(2*x)
    comm = (2*w + x)
    part1 = ((v**2 + 4*w*(w + 2*x) + 2*x*(x - 1))*fac**5
        + 2*u*fac**4
        + (-v**2 - 4*(w*(3*w + 4*x + 1) + x*(x-2)) + 1)*fac**3
        + (-8*(w + x) + 2)*fac**2
        + (2*comm*(comm + 1) - 1)*fac)
    return part1/lmbd *besselj(n+1, lmbd) * besselj(k+1, lmbd)

def perform_quad(n, k, a):
    return quad(complicated_func, 0, np.inf, args=(a,n,k))[0]

def improved_main():
    sz = 20
    amatrix = np.zeros((sz,sz))
    ls = -np.linspace(1, 10, 20)/2
    inds = np.tril_indices(sz)
    myv3 = np.vectorize(perform_quad)
    res = myv3(inds[0], inds[1], ls.reshape(-1,1))
    results = np.empty(res.shape[0])
    for rowind, row in enumerate(res):
        amatrix[inds] = row
        symm_matrix = amatrix + amatrix.T - np.diag(amatrix.diagonal())
        results[rowind] = norm(symm_matrix)
    return results
```

Timing results show me a speed increase of a factor 5 (you'll forgive me if I only ran it once, it takes long enough as it is):

```
In [11]: %timeit -n1 -r1 improved_main()
1 loops, best of 1: 6.92 s per loop

In [12]: %timeit -n1 -r1 main()
1 loops, best of 1: 35.9 s per loop
```

There was also a microgain to be had if you replaced `v` immediately by its square, because that's the only time it is used in that complicated function: as its square.

There's also an extreme amount of repetition in the calls to `besselj`, but I don't see how to avoid that, because `quad` will determine `lmbd`, so you can't easily precompute those values and then perform a lookup.

If you profile the `improved_main`, you'll see that the amount of calls to `complicated_func` has nearly decreased by a factor of 2 (the diagonal still needs to be computed). All the other speed gains can be attributed to `np.vectorize` and the improvements to `complicated_func`.

I don't have Matlab on my system, so I can't make any statements for its speed gain if you improve the complicated function there.

Comment: I completely overlook the fact that this matrix is symmetric. With that and vectorization I got the timing of 7s, so it seems that the simplifications inside `f `are not so useful (I mean `x`, `fac` and `comm` precomputed values). Thank you, Oliver, for these improvements.

Comment: @vaeea You're welcome. I thought it was an interesting problem, because it doesn't lend itself easily to vectorization. By the way, I read that `np.vectorize` is more of a convenience function that wraps some loops, rather than the real vectorization people usually mean by the term. I too saw its use more in wrapping the loops over `n, k` and `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `numpy` version probably is comparable in to speed to older MATLAB runs.  But new MATLAB versions do various forms of just-in-time compilation that speed up repeated calculations considerably.

My guess is that you can nibble away at the `lambda` and `f` code, and maybe cut their evaluation times in half.  But the real killer is that you are calling `f` so many times.

For a start I'd try to precalculate things in `f`.  For example define `K1=K[1]` and use `K1` in the calculations.  That will reduce the number of indexing calls.  Are of the exponentials repeated?  Maybe replace the `lambda` definition with a regular `def`, or combine it with `f`.